# Which is better for performance - using php-qt or writing custom php extensions for c++ using swig?

Tags: php, c++, qt, swig, php-qt

I'm writing a php web application using Yii and need to use C++ (will use Qt-Core) for some performance critical parts. I have two options:

i) Using php-qt and write those parts using qt bindings for php.
ii) Write those parts in C++/Qt and using swig to generate php extensions to use in my php app.

Which one would you suggest from a performance standpoint?
 How much difference would there be between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I like Qt quite a bit, but if performance is your concern I would take the swig path.